# Added a second controller to my WebAPI and it is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Added a second controller in my WebAPI project and it is nor working completely but the first controller is working as expected

The default URI works for the first controller to return all records:
http://localhost:59654/api/TidalBatch

The second controller does not work and returns the error in question:
http://localhost:59654/api/TidalBatchConsolidated

However, if I pass in {id} for it, it does work for when I use the id (example shown):
http://localhost:59654/api/TidalBatchConsolidated/BAM

Tried modifying the routing addresses

WebAPI config:
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "TidalBatchApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "TidalBatchConsolidatedApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/TidalBatchConsolidated/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I have 2 controllers, `TidalBatchController.cs` and `TidalBatchConsolidatedController.cs`. Both inherit from `ApiController` class.

Here's an example of my second controller that is not working as expected:

```
 public class TidalBatchConsolidatedController : ApiController 
 {
   public TidalBatchConsolidated GetAll(string id) 
   { 
     using (BDW_ProcessingEntities_TidalBatch entities = new BDW_ProcessingEntities_TidalBatch()) 
     { 
       return entities.TidalBatchConsolidateds.FirstOrDefault(e => e.CompanyAbbr == id); 
     } 
   } 
 }
```

When I navigate to the base controller in the address it should return the List results in JSON format based on which entity data model is being passed in.

Comment: Here's an example of my second controller that is not working as expected:     public class TidalBatchConsolidatedController : ApiController
    {
        public TidalBatchConsolidated GetAll(string id)
        {
            using (BDW_ProcessingEntities_TidalBatch entities = new BDW_ProcessingEntities_TidalBatch())
            {
                return entities.TidalBatchConsolidateds.FirstOrDefault(e => e.CompanyAbbr == id);
            }
        }              
    }

Comment: Please paste your controler code in your question

Comment: Try with add `/` after URL like this `http://localhost:59654/api/TidalBatchConsolidated/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the order you register routes is important where more generic routes need to be registered after more specific routes. Secondly you more specific route needs controller in order for it to match.

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "TidalBatchConsolidatedApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/TidalBatchConsolidated/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller ="TidalBatchConsolidated", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "TidalBatchApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The controller also needs to ensure that there is a matching action

For example

```
public class TidalBatchConsolidatedController: ApiController {

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get() {
        //...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string id) {
        //...
    }

}
```

Since you have attribute routing enabled with `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`, you could forego convention based route and use attribute routing on the controller instead

```
[RoutePrefix("api/TidalBatchConsolidated")]
public class TidalBatchConsolidatedController: ApiController {

    //GET api/TidalBatchConsolidated
    [Route("")] //Default route
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAll() {
        //...
    }


    //GET api/TidalBatchConsolidated/BAM
    [Route("{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string id) {
        //...
    }

}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: This should work without the first route. The specific route in your answer can be removed. The more generic route is the same like the specif route.

Comment: @mrspringer yes I know but wanted to show OP about specifying the defaults.

Comment: Thanks. I made the edits as mentioned but I still get No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:59654/api/TidalBatchConsolidated' error.

Comment: @TimothyRodriguez what should happen when no id is provided?

Comment: it returns all records of the table set. For ex: if I call the URI for api/TidalBatch/ then all the records for it are populated akin to GET ALL. For some reason it doesnt do same for TidalBatchConsolidated unless I pass in id to it: api/TidalBatchConsolidated/<something>

Comment: @TimothyRodriguez You were most likely missing a matching action. Check updated answer

Comment: Well dang it that didnt work either. Here's what I have:     namespace BDW_REST_services.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/TidalBatchConsolidated")]
    public class TidalBatchConsolidatedController : ApiController
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] //Default route
    public IEnumerable<TidalBatchConsolidated> GetAll(string id)
        {
            using (BDW_ProcessingEntities_TidalBatch entities = new BDW_ProcessingEntities_TidalBatch())
            {
                return entities.TidalBatchConsolidateds.ToList();
            }
}

Comment: {
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:59654/api/TidalBatchConsolidated'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'TidalBatchConsolidated' that matches the request."
}